# Generating float numbers from integer decimal index in Python

Tags: python, string, floating-point

Given I have any given index integer how can I generate float numbers or strings which references the decimal point as 0

Examples:

```
Given an increment factor digit 1:
n=-4 ~ "0.0001"
n=-10 ~ "0.0000000001"
```

```
Given an increment factor digit 2:
n=1 ~ "2.0"
n=5 ~ "20000.0"
n=-5 ~ "0.00002"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use scientific notation:

```py
n = 1e-4  # 0.0001
n = 1e-10 # 0.0000000001
n = 2e1   # 2.0
n = 2e5   # 20000.0
n = 2e-5  # 0.00005
```

This is built into python. Doing something like

```py
x = 5.3e6
```

is equivalent to doing

```py
x = 5.3 * (10 ** 6)
```

It is worth noting that while the number before `e` may be a float itself, the number after `e` (the power of 10) must be an integer. Also note that this returns floating point numbers always so if you wanted it as a string for some reason you would have to call `str()` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need a power of ten in there. So take the digit, `d`, and multiply it by `10^n`. When doing this however you should take note that the positive numbers are one factor of 10 off since it starts at 0, not 1. To fix that just subtract one from n if it's positive. This lambda does the trick: `lambda n: n-1 if (n>0) else n`

```
# When the factor (d) is 1
n=2      f = d*10^n     "100.0"
n=-1     f = d*10^n     "0.1"

# When the factor (d) is 2
n = 4    f = d*10^n     "20000.0"
n = -5   f = d*10^n     "0.00002"
```